# Reduce Travis-CI building time for Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, travis-ci

I've started a new project of SprintBoot and Kotlin and I wanted to use Travis-CI as my CI server.

I also wanted to use `codecov` to collect the reports about my code coverage

Everything seems to work perfectly beside one thing, My project currently is an empty SpringBoot project that contains (and no tests) and the build itself takes up to 2m (mostly due to the time it takes to install Gradle).

I checked on their site and saw some optimizations to the build, but they're looked to early for this stage of the project (e.g. parallel tests execution).

Am I missing something? is 2m is the baseline for Travis-CI building time?

My current configurations for Travis :

```
# This enables the 'defaults' to test java applications:
language: java

# We can specify a list of JDKs to be used for testing
# A list of available JDKs in Trusty can be seed in:
# https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/xenial/#jvm-clojure-groovy-java-scala-support
jdk:
  - openjdk11

before_script:
  # makes sure that gradle commands can be executed on build
  - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  # Makes sure that gradle can be executed.
  - ./gradlew check
  # Generates the reports for codecov
  - ./gradlew jacocoTestReport

# This is to enable CodeCov's coverage
# If a build is successful, the code is submitted for coverage analysis
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to cache to improve speeds of your build on Travis. Gradle has a dedicated guide on building on Travis: https://guides.gradle.org/executing-gradle-builds-on-travisci/

For caching, scroll down to [Enable caching of downloaded artifacts](https://guides.gradle.org/executing-gradle-builds-on-travisci/#enable_caching_of_downloaded_artifacts)

Comment: Mostly because the documentation is a bit out-dated - so for people in the future that would like to know: In order to fix that you need to add the following plugin https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.build-scan and the following configurations: https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/